# Can't change instance network using terraform in gcp

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I have a couple of unmanaged compute instances belonging to an instance group. I created them using terraform and when I tried to modify the instances networks (put them into another vpc) I got this error:

```
Error: Error updating network interface: googleapi: Error 400: The instance resource 'projects/my-varan-project/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/test-vm-1' is already being used by 'projects/my-varan-project/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroups/test-ig-1', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
```

Any thoughts?